# Xamarin module app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, windows-phone

So, our clients contacted us and they want to create app in Xamarin(Android, Ios, Windows Phone) that will be able to do next:

- First, we need to create a core application that will have basic elements(login/register/main dashboard)
- Second part, they want to create some modules for the app so that user can download it from the store as an expansion. So, for instance, user installed core app, logs in, and now, he has a choice to upgrade this app with modules: calculator, currency converter, etc. Now, he doesn't want calculator, but he wants currency converter, so, hell just download that and update current application with that module. After few days he needs a calendar module that we built, he then downloads that module, etc...

Can this be achieved via Xamarin or does it need to be native. Please tell me more about both cases.

Comment: iOS does not allow that (Xamarin-based app or not), you are in a sandboxed environment and the only *code* that is allowed to be memory executed is code that was originally signed. The only exception to that is Apple's Nitro/JavaScriptCore, so you could develop it all as an embedded web app using html/javascript....

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for info. Can you tell me if this is the same for WIndows Mobile and Android? And if there is some workaround?

Comment: On Android you *could* download a CIL-based assembly, load it and execute code as JIT'ing code and executing it on the "fly" is allowed. I do not believe there is any way to do that on Windows Mobile. The solution that makes the most sense is to add your new "module" features to the app, release an updated version of it to the various app stores and allow the users to unlock "features" via in-App purchases. The various app stores will of course take their percentage of the purchase.

Comment: On IOS you already could add all modules in the beginning and just activate or deactivate them on user actions.

Comment: thank you guys for info.

Comment: Hi Milijan, I want to create basically the same kind of application. Did you go further ? I'm thinking about another option : develop the modules as other application and then use inter process communication to communicate between my application and the "modules".

Comment: @JulienFerraro Hey! So, basically, what could be done, for android and windows applications is next:
you create a core app, put it on the store, then, you develop "modules" that will actually be new apps, and in code, you insert some conditions where you won't be able to open this app without core app. Something similar to Facebook and Messanger. Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @Miljan, I was thinking more about adding a functionnality to an application. Imagine a sales application, if you have the module, you can connect to a Sum'Up to pay, another module could connect to another credit card reader.

Comment: I have the feeling that, in this case, inter process communication would be too slow. IF only I could just put a DLL in the application folder and load it at runtime if it's present ...

Comment: @JulienFerraro actually, it wouldn't be slow. It gets to this:
Do you want to create one big application where you will via roles enable or disable some funcionality?
Do you want to creat one app that is the base and then add other apps with authorization from the base one?
Based on what you want, it would be maybe best to create one big app where you will permit/forbid some funcionality to some users.

Comment: @Milijan, I want to achive the following : Create an application that provides some sort of API and let developpers create their own plugins. I asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216347/xamarin-and-managed-extensibility-framework-mef) about this.